# Interpolate between linear and nonlinear values

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I have been able to interpolate values successfully from linear values of `x` to sine-like values of `y`.
However - I am struggling to interpolate the other way - from nonlinear values of `y` to linear values of `x`.

The below is a toy example

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from scipy import interpolate
#create 100 x values
x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 100)
#create 100 values of y where y= sin(x)
y=np.sin(x)
#learn function to map y from x
f = interpolate.interp1d(x, y)
```

With new values of linear `x`

```
xnew = np.array([-1,1])
```

I get correctly interpolated values of nonlinear `y`

```
ynew = f(xnew)
print(ynew)    
array([-0.84114583,  0.84114583])
```

The problem comes when I try and interpolate values of `x` from `y`.

I create a new function, the reverse of f:

```
f2 = interpolate.interp1d(y,x,kind='cubic')
```

I put in values of y that I successfully interpolated before

```
ynew=np.array([-0.84114583, 0.84114583])
```

I am expecting to  get the original values of `x` [-1, 1]

But I get:

```
array([-1.57328791,  1.57328791])
```

I have tried putting in other values for the 'kind' parameter with no luck and am not sure if I have got the wrong approach here.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem raises from the fact, that `x` is not a function of `y`, since for an arbitrary `y` value there may be more than one `x` value found.

Take a look at a truncated range of data.
When `x` ranges from 0 to `np.pi/2`, then for every `y` value there is a unique `x` value.
In this case the snippet below works as expected.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy import interpolate
>>> x = np.linspace(0, np.pi / 2, 100)
>>> y = np.sin(x)
>>> f = interpolate.interp1d(x, y)
>>> f([0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5])
array([0.        , 0.09983071, 0.29551713, 0.47941047])
>>> f2 = interpolate.interp1d(y, x)
>>> f2([0, 0.09983071, 0.29551713, 0.47941047])
array([0.        , 0.1       , 0.3       , 0.50000001])
```

Comment: thanks - that makes sense. Wanted to make sure I wasnt completely on the wrong track here. I am not a math expert!

Answer (score 0):

Maxim provided the reason for this behavior. This interpolation is a class designed to work for functions. In your case, `y=arcsin(x)` is only in a limited interval a function. This leads to interesting phenomena in the interpolation routine that interpolates to the nearest y-value which in the case of the `arcsin()` function is not necessarily the next value in the x-y curve but maybe several periods away. An illustration:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from scipy import interpolate
xmin=-np.pi
xmax=np.pi

fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 3, figsize=(15, 10))

for i, fac in enumerate([2, 1, 0.5]):
    x = np.linspace(xmin * fac, xmax*fac, 100)
    y=np.sin(x)
    
    #x->y
    f = interpolate.interp1d(x, y)
    x_fit = np.linspace(xmin*fac, xmax*fac, 1000)
    y_fit = f(x_fit)
    axes[i][0].plot(x_fit, y_fit)
    axes[i][0].set_ylabel(f"sin period {fac}")
    if not i:
        axes[i][0].set_title(label="interpolation x->y")
        

    #y->x
    f2 = interpolate.interp1d(y, x)
    y2_fit = np.linspace(.99 * min(y), .99 * max(y), 1000)
    x2_fit = f2(y2_fit)
    axes[i][1].plot(x2_fit, y2_fit)
    if not i:
        axes[i][1].set_title(label="interpolation y->x")
    
    #y->x with cubic interpolation
    f3 = interpolate.interp1d(y, x, kind="cubic")
    y3_fit = np.linspace(.99 * min(y), .99 * max(y), 1000)
    x3_fit = f3(y3_fit)
    axes[i][2].plot(x3_fit, y3_fit)
    if not i:
        axes[i][2].set_title(label="cubic interpolation y->x")
    
    
plt.show()
```

[image]

As you can see, the interpolation works along the ordered list of y-values (as you instructed it to), and this works particularly badly with cubic interpolation.